# Embedding feature vectors in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

In text processing there is [embedding](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/embedding) to show up (if I understood it correctly) the database words as vector (after dimension reduction). 
now, I am wondering, is there any method like this to show extracted features via CNN?

for example: consider we have a CNN and train and test sets. we want to train the CNN with train set and meanwhile see the extracted features (from dense layer) corresponding class labels via CNN in the embedding section of tensorboard.

the purpose of this work is seeing the features of input data in every batch and understand how close or far are they from together. and finally, in the trained model, we can find out accuracy of our classifier (like softmax or etc.).

thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken help of Tensorflow documentation.

For in depth information on how to run TensorBoard and make sure you are logging all the necessary information, see [TensorBoard: Visualizing Learning.](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/embedding_viz/)

To visualize your embeddings, there are 3 things you need to do:

**1) Setup a 2D tensor that holds your embedding(s).**

```
embedding_var = tf.get_variable(....)
```

**2) Periodically save your model variables in a checkpoint in LOG_DIR.**

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(session, os.path.join(LOG_DIR, "model.ckpt"), step)
```

**3) (Optional) Associate metadata with your embedding.**

If you have any metadata (labels, images) associated with your embedding, you can tell TensorBoard about it either by directly storing a projector_config.pbtxt in the LOG_DIR, or use our python API.

For instance, the following projector_config.ptxt associates the word_embedding tensor with metadata stored in $LOG_DIR/metadata.tsv:

```
embeddings {
  tensor_name: 'word_embedding'
  metadata_path: '$LOG_DIR/metadata.tsv'
}
```

The same config can be produced programmatically using the following code snippet:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

# Create randomly initialized embedding weights which will be trained.
vocabulary_size = 10000
embedding_size = 200
embedding_var = tf.get_variable('word_embedding', [vocabulary_size, 
embedding_size])

# Format: tensorflow/tensorboard/plugins/projector/projector_config.proto
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()

# You can add multiple embeddings. Here we add only one.
embedding = config.embeddings.add()
embedding.tensor_name = embedding_var.name
# Link this tensor to its metadata file (e.g. labels).
embedding.metadata_path = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'metadata.tsv')

#Use the same LOG_DIR where you stored your checkpoint.
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR)

# The next line writes a projector_config.pbtxt in the LOG_DIR. TensorBoard will
# read this file during startup.
projector.visualize_embeddings(summary_writer, config)
```